# Include Tests to run in build process Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have been working on a module, whenever it is build using "gradlew assemble"it will generate an aar file in build/output folder. I have created few tests extending the InstrumentationTestCase in android app module, I want to run those tests whenever I build the library using gradle command.If compilation of tests "pass" the build(aar) should happen else it should fail. Could any one please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `gradlew clean connectedCheck` should run through all of your tests on all connected devices and will also build out your aar file. That's the easiest way.

Comment: Thanks it helped with out creating seperate tasks for tests in gradle.

Comment: Happy to hear it helped. When you get the chance feel free to mark this as the selected answer :)

Comment: I encountered a problem when using gradlew connectedCheck it doesnt replace the new aar builds. Instead I used 'gradlew clean  connectedCheck' this command refreshes the  builds in aar folder.

Comment: Calling clean is a safe way to ensure it does a full rebuild every time but if you made code changes it should still generate a new aar file. I updated my answer to include the clean command though.